# Funções parametrizadas - calculaValorDevido

Tags: javascript, funções

Estou tendo as primeiras aulas de JavaScript, entao minhas duvidas são simples. Enunciado:

> Depois de nossa consultoria, a lavanderia DigitalLaundry percebeu que
> poderia deixar a sua cobrança mais sofisticada e justa. Ela decidiu
> cobrar R$10,00 fixo, a título de taxa de serviço (independente da
> quantidade de roupa), mais R$ 3,00 por quilo de roupa suja. Reescreva
> a função calculaValorDevido
>
> ```
> function calculaValorDevido(pesoDeRoupaSuja){
>   ...
> }
> ```
>
> Essa função recebe como único parâmetro a quantidade de roupa suja.
> Ela deve retornar o valor a ser cobrado do cliente usando a nova
> política de preços.

Meu código até então:

```js
console.log(calculaValorDevido(10));



function calculaValorDevido(pesoDaRoupaSuja) {
    var pesoroupaSuja 
    pesoDaRoupaSuja * 3
    var fixo = 10.00
    
      return fixo + pesoDaRoupaSuja
    }
```

O erro é:

> Há algo errado com sua multiplicação, verifique se você está
> retornando corretamente a multiplicação

Comment: Você escreveu o enunciado, uma tentativa. Qual a dúvida afinal?

Answer (score 1):

Considere o seguinte.

Primeiro: Você está multiplicando o pesoDaRoupaSuja com 3, mas não está salvando esse novo valor.
Segundo: Você não precisa declarar uma variável que recebeu como parâmetro na função.

```js
console.log(calculaValorDevido(10));



function calculaValorDevido(pesoDaRoupaSuja) {
    let ValorPeso = pesoDaRoupaSuja * 3;
    var fixo = 10.00;
    
      return fixo + ValorPeso;
    }
```

Comment: funcionou @rebeca , Muito Obrigado!

Comment: Se a resposta foi útil, pode marcá-la como resposta da pergunta. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar da seguinte maneira:

```js
  console.log(calculaValorDevido(10));
  
  
  function calculaValorDevido(pesoDaRoupaSuja){
    
    return ( 10 + (pesoDaRoupaSuja * 3))
    
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
// Configurações
const preco_fixo = 10
const taxa_por_quilo = 3
// Função
function calculaValorDevido(peso_da_roupa) {
  let resultado=peso_da_roupa*taxa_por_quilo; // Aplicando a taxa p/ Kg
  resultado+=preco_fixo; // Adicionando o preço fixo
  return resultado;
}
// Testando
console.log(calculaValorDevido(2))
```